# Which episode has Onizuka getting the kanji wrong?

Tags: great-teacher-onizuka

I saw *GTO* a while ago, and now I need to find out in which episode of the anime he writes a kanji wrong (辛, spicy, instead of 幸, happiness).

I know that in the manga there is an episode in Lesson 51 / 52 where he writes like "tax sex" instead of "best of Japan" after scoring top grade in the public tests, which should be around episode 15 - 16 in the anime, but the scene got deleted and anyway the setting I remember is quite different.

I think the scene I remember takes place on the school roof, with the boys correcting him. I have nothing more than this, besides a few hypothesis. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from episode 23, "Superstition". The summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Great_Teacher_Onizuka_episodes):

> Eikichi receives a cursed chain letter, but he dismisses it as superstition. After a series of misfortunes, he begins to believe in the letter and does whatever he can (including suggestions from Kanzaki to write spells all over himself) to dispel the curse.

In Japan, the "cursed chain letter" is infamously known as 不幸の手紙 (*fukou no tegami*, misfortune letter), usually begins with

> これは不幸の手紙です。
>   This is a misfortune letter.

However, in this episode, Onizuka instead wrote

> これは**不辛**の手紙です。
>   This is a **non-spicy** letter.

---

The setting was actually inside the classroom, not on the school roof, and the boys (and girls too) were mocking Onizuka.

Comment: You're perfectly right, episode 23 was among my guesses, but my hunch about the roof put me on the wrong track. Thank you!